# OpenCV library not able to read the .mp4 video file to create the VideoCapture object

Tags: c++, linux, opencv, video-capture, amazon-linux

I am trying to capture frames from a video using **OpenCV** and following [this](https://www.learnopencv.com/read-write-and-display-a-video-using-opencv-cpp-python/) article.
But due to some reasons the OpenCV is not able to create the `VideoCapture` object which will capture the frames. The file is .mp4 format which is same as that of file used in the article.

The code is as below:

```
#include "opencv4/opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp"
// highgui - an interface to video and image capturing.

#include <iostream> 
// The header files for performing input and output.

using namespace cv;
// Namespace where all the C++ OpenCV functionality resides.

using namespace std;
// For input output operations.


int main()
{
    VideoCapture cap("Vid1.mp4");
    // cap is the object of class video capture that tries to capture Bumpy.mp4
    if ( !cap.isOpened() )  // isOpened() returns true if capturing has been initialized.
    {
        cout << "Cannot open the video file. \n";
        return -1;
    }
    else {
        printf("File has been opened \n");

    }
}
```

When I build the executable and run it I get the output on console: **Cannot open the video file.**

Now as mentioned [here](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/issues/10378#issuecomment-353425674) I added the environment var. `OPENCV_VIDEOCAPTURE_DEBUG=1` to see the logs from opencv and found the following **logs** on console:

```
[ WARN:0] global /home/user/opencv/modules/videoio/src/cap.cpp (108) open VIDEOIO(FFMPEG): trying capture filename='Vid1.mp4' ...
[ WARN:0] global /home/user/opencv/modules/videoio/src/cap.cpp (170) open VIDEOIO(FFMPEG): backend is not available (plugin is missing, or can't be loaded due dependencies or it is not compatible)
[ WARN:0] global /home/user/opencv/modules/videoio/src/cap.cpp (108) open VIDEOIO(GSTREAMER): trying capture filename='Vid1.mp4' ...
[ WARN:0] global /home/user/opencv/modules/videoio/src/cap.cpp (170) open VIDEOIO(GSTREAMER): backend is not available (plugin is missing, or can't be loaded due dependencies or it is not compatible)
[ WARN:0] global /home/user/opencv/modules/videoio/src/cap.cpp (108) open VIDEOIO(INTEL_MFX): trying capture filename='Vid1.mp4' ...
[ WARN:0] global /home/user/opencv/modules/videoio/src/cap.cpp (170) open VIDEOIO(INTEL_MFX): backend is not available (plugin is missing, or can't be loaded due dependencies or it is not compatible)
[ WARN:0] global /home/user/opencv/modules/videoio/src/cap.cpp (108) open VIDEOIO(V4L2): trying capture filename='Vid1.mp4' ...
[ WARN:0] global /home/user/opencv/modules/videoio/src/cap.cpp (131) open VIDEOIO(V4L2): can't create capture
[ WARN:0] global /home/user/opencv/modules/videoio/src/cap.cpp (108) open VIDEOIO(CV_IMAGES): trying capture filename='Vid1.mp4' ...
[ WARN:0] global /home/user/opencv/modules/videoio/src/cap.cpp (120) open VIDEOIO(CV_IMAGES): created, isOpened=0
[ WARN:0] global /home/user/opencv/modules/videoio/src/cap.cpp (108) open VIDEOIO(CV_MJPEG): trying capture filename='Vid1.mp4' ...
[ WARN:0] global /home/user/opencv/modules/videoio/src/cap.cpp (131) open VIDEOIO(CV_MJPEG): can't create capture
```

Could someone explain why `VideoCapture` object creation is failing?

Comment: Can I ask how you installed opencv?

Comment: Followed this  - https://docs.opencv.org/trunk/d7/d9f/tutorial_linux_install.html